# How to add a new pandas column whose value is conditioned on one column, but value depends on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
idx  group  valA  valB 
-----------------------
0    A      10    5
1    A      22    7
2    B      9     0
3    B      6     1
```

I want to add a new column 'val' that takes 'valA' if group = 'A' and takes 'valB' if group = 'B'.

```
idx  group  valA  valB  val
---------------------------
0    A      10    5     10
1    A      22    7     22
2    B      9     0     0 
3    B      6     1     1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: there are myriads of available answers to your question, here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Comment: I disagree with my question being a duplicate. In the linked question, the output depends only on the value of the conditional column. In my question, the output is conditioned on one column, but the value of the output depends on other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```py
df['val'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['valA'] if x['group'] == 'A' else x['valB'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! How might I modify it if there are more than two groups? (without doing nested if statements)